# Retrieve hidden text from remote page using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to extract all the reviews from AirBNB to conduct a sentiment analysis. Now I have a page with 18 reviews [here](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/22881110?location=New%20York%2C%20NY&source_impression_id=p3_1594278077_bstIT9s0ZbMsyH%2Fr&guests=1&adults=1), but the page shows only 6 reviews (some reviews are hidden with a link "show more") and 18 reviews are shown only after clicking "show all 18 reviews".

I am automating the text extraction with Selenium and not all pages have 18 reviews. I am using XPath to locate the div that contains all the reviews, but it seems the reviews are loaded with javascript using

```
<div data-plugin-in-point id="Reviews_default", data-section-id="reviews_default"....'some padding attributes here' tabindex=-1>
```

To find the element I am using:

```
br.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/section').text
```

`br` is a reference to the Selenium object

How can I extract all the text from the reviews in this div? I am not posting the whole code with automation here since I think if I can get this one page done I can handle the automation to extract reviews from all 94 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
element.get_attribute("textContent")
```

instead of

```
element.text
```